# count number of rows in uitable

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I'm having trouble counting the number of rows in my uitable.

```
data={'for' '32' '1'
      '123' 'tired' '3g'
      '0' 'door' 'roof'};
w=uitable('data',data,'position',[100 100 100 100])
```

I have tried the command height, but i get an error saying

```
Undefined function 'height' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in boundary_conditions (line 9)
height(w)
```

Comment: What about `size(data,1)`? Or you just see the final uitable?

Comment: you just made me feel so stupid :D thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part initialize the `uitable` and display it:

```
data={'for' '32' '1'                               
'123' 'tired' '3g'                                 
'0' 'door' 'roof'};                                
w=uitable('data',data,'position',[100 100 100 100])
```

now in order to `get`/`set` object properties one may follow this [howto](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-a-set-get-interface-for-properties.html). Here is an example of getting for your needs:

```
prop = {'data','position'};                                                       
attributes = get(w,prop);
>> attributes

attributes = 

    {3x3 cell}    [1x4 double]

>> attributes{1}

ans = 

    'for'    '32'       '1'   
    '123'    'tired'    '3g'  
    '0'      'door'     'roof'

>> size(attributes{1},1)

ans =

     3
```